# Can GNU parallel print out the progress bar for scripts it calls?

Tags: r, gnu-parallel

Given an RScript that prints out it's own progress bar, say `myscript.R`:

```
pBar <- txtProgressBar(style = 1)
L <- 10L

for (m1 in seq_len(L)) {
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  setTxtProgressBar(pb = pBar,
                    value = m1 / L)
}
```

Can I get GNU parallel tools to print out the progress bars from my script? Will it manage new sets of progress bars?

My typical usage of parallel something like:

```
parallel --jobs 5 --progress "RScript ~/myrscript.R {#}" ::: `seq 20`
```

I'd like to be able to see each progress bar print out, and then either bars for the next set replace the first, or print underneath on new lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
parallel --jobs 5 -u RScript ~/myrscript.R {#} ::: `seq 20`
```

`--ungroup/-u` will pass all output directly.

It is probably not ideal: The progress bar from each process will overwrite the previous job's progress bar.

Or try using `--tmux`:

```
parallel --jobs 5 --tmux --bar RScript ~/myrscript.R {#} ::: `seq 20`
```

This will start each job in a `tmux` window, so you can see the output from each job. `--bar` will give a progress bar based on completed jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This seems to be going in the right direction, but I'm not entirely sure what it's doing. With the initial example script it *seems* to just print out all the progress bars together as though they're one large multiline progress bar? Changing to `txtProgressBar(style = 3)` shows a single progress bar that ... appears to be being written over multiple times as it completes?